# Push an element to bottom of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the layout built like the following:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="pushBottom">Bottom Content</div>
  <div> Something </div>
  <div>Something </div>
</div>
```

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
Something
Something
Bottom Content
```

Comment: where is the css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

> ... you can target individual items and change where they
> appear in the visual order with the `order` property.
>
> ... items are assigned an integer that represents their group. The items are then placed in the visual order according to that integer, lowest values first. If more than one item has the same integer value, then within that group the items are laid out as per source order.
>
> [MDN - Ordering Flex Items - The Order Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property)

Here's an example:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pushBottom {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="pushBottom">Bottom Content</div>
  <div>Something</div>
  <div>Something</div>
</div>
```

Also note that:

> The reordering capabilities of flex layout intentionally affect only the visual rendering, leaving speech order and navigation based on the source order.
>
> Authors must not use order or the *-reverse values of flex-flow/flex-direction as a substitute for correct source ordering, as that can ruin the accessibility of the document.
>
> [W3 - CSS Flexible Box Layout - Ordering and Orientation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flow-order)

You may also want to check the browser compatibility of `flex`.
At the time of this post, [vendor prefixes](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) are recommended for older browsers.

Comment: I would avoid using `3` as we may think we need that number to be equal to position that should have the element so if we had 5 element we need to use `6`... using `1` is enough ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see your point. Don't want to give the wrong impression.